# HTTP header location doesn't work

Tags: php, http, mysqli, http-headers

This code use protect function . to do **permission access level**

header location doesn't work and 
 **I look at address bar  found it still in protect page**

this is "protect page":

```
 foreach($access_level as $k => $v)
        {
        //  print_r($v); //   output  12    
    protect($v);// call function in loop to get the values of array 
        }

   global $v ;
function protect($v){

 if($_SESSION['sessionloginid']==true && $v ==1)
        {

header(" location: http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/display/display.php");

        }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried a relative URL?

Comment: First of all, remove the `global $v`, its useless. Second, make sure a session has been started with `session_start()` and third, you should exit the script after the `header("");` and make sure no output has been given before the `header()` call ..

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get errors?

Comment: Try removing the space before "location" - and if you echo anything else before the redirection - don't.

Comment: I noticed that earlier also @matcarlson

Comment: it was because of space before location header thank you all of people reply

Comment: I write the question again because it is not solved and no replay after some times ago .what I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space in the HTTP header. Try

```
header("location: http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/display/display.php");
```

instead of

```
header(" location: http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/display/display.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, removed some space infront of `header("location")`

```
     function protect($v){
         global $v ;
         session_start();
         if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']) && $_SESSION['sessionloginid']==true && $v ==1)
          {
            header("location: http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/display/display.php"); 
          }
     }
```